# Is there no way to have transparent status bar on iOS in React Native > 0.60

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, statusbar

Before I switched to RN 0.62 from RN 0.47 it's been pretty simple to support transparent status bar on both iOS and Android by just replacing Stack Navigation header with the StatusBar. Just specifying bar style was enough, it was transparent by default. I tried the same approach after the RN update, and now it does not seem to work.

```
<Stack.Screen
        name="WelcomeScreen"
        component={WelcomeScreen} 
        options={{
          header: props =>  <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent"/>, //<Header barStyle='dark-content' />,
          gestureEnabled: false
        }}
```

The piece above demonstrates what I attempted to do. The replacement itself does not yield any errors, changing 'barStyle' does affect the content color, but the background is static white, and can't figure out the way to change it. From StatusBar component documentation I found out that 'translucent' and 'backgroundColor' properties are only supported on Android. So, is it true that there is absolutely no way to accomplish this without going deep into native code ? I'd be glad to know for sure whether there is a workaround or not, since in worst case I'll just make customer swallow the fact that this kind of microadjustments of UI are too costly, but I have to be sure.

Comment: Status bar in iOS is _always_ transparent.

Comment: I do understand it, and the problem certainly has to do with react-navigation library, but replacing it with some custom stuff is something we cannot afford ATM

Comment: You're not supposed to replace the `Header` with `StatusBar` component, it's for header. If you want to hide the header, then specify `headerShown: false`, and render the `StatusBar` component inside your screen along with `useIsFocused` hook (`isFocused && <StatusBar ... />`)